# Possible to compile razor templates to a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am working on a project which sends emails and I want to create HTML templates using Razor but all the tutorials and docs I have seen online only show a way to use Razor to return views in response to a request. I want to render the HTML and then pass it to my email sending code. Is this possible? Or is anyone aware of another templating engine that will work with dotnet core?

Answer (score 3):

In this sample, you might find everything that you need for your goal: https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/master/samples/Mvc.RenderViewToString

Example of code:

**RazorViewToString.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace RenderRazorToString
{
    public class RazorViewToString
    {
        private readonly IRazorViewEngine _viewEngine;
        private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public RazorViewToString(
            IRazorViewEngine viewEngine,
            ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _viewEngine = viewEngine;
            _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task<string> RenderViewToString<TModel>(string name, TModel model)
        {
            var actionContext = GetActionContext();

            var viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, name, false);

            if (!viewEngineResult.Success)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Couldn't find view '{0}'", name));
            }

            var view = viewEngineResult.View;

            using (var output = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    view,
                    new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                        metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                        modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                    {
                        Model = model
                    },
                    new TempDataDictionary(
                        actionContext.HttpContext,
                        _tempDataProvider),
                    output,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions());

                await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);

                return output.ToString();
            }
        }

        private ActionContext GetActionContext()
        {
            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
            {
                RequestServices = _serviceProvider
            };

            return new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
        }
    }
}
```

View model class:

**EmailViewModel.cs**

```
namespace RenderRazorToString
{
    public class EmailViewModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string SenderName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And layout and view files:

**Views/_EmailLayout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <footer>
Thanks,<br />
@Model.SenderName
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**Views/EmailTemplate.cshtml**

```
@model RenderRazorToString.EmailViewModel
@{ 
    Layout = "_EmailLayout";
}

Hello @Model.UserName,

<p>
    This is a generic email about something.<br />
    <br />
</p>
```

In console app you just need to initialize some services, and call it:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool;
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;

namespace RenderRazorToString
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Initialize the necessary services
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureDefaultServices(services);
            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var renderer = provider.GetRequiredService<RazorViewToString>();

            // Build a model and render a view
            var model = new EmailViewModel
            {
                UserName = "User",
                SenderName = "Sender"
            };
            var emailContent = renderer.RenderViewToString("EmailTemplate", model).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.WriteLine(emailContent);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void ConfigureDefaultServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var applicationEnvironment = PlatformServices.Default.Application;
            services.AddSingleton(applicationEnvironment);

            var appDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

            var environment = new HostingEnvironment
            {
                WebRootFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(appDirectory),
                ApplicationName = "RenderRazorToString"
            };
            services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>(environment);

            services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.FileProviders.Clear();
                options.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(appDirectory));
            });

            services.AddSingleton<ObjectPoolProvider, DefaultObjectPoolProvider>();

            var diagnosticSource = new DiagnosticListener("Microsoft.AspNetCore");
            services.AddSingleton<DiagnosticSource>(diagnosticSource);

            services.AddLogging();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSingleton<RazorViewToString>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question asked. While helpful, he's asking to render the template from a string format, not from a compiled view.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [Rendering Razor to string](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1312081), you can also create the razor string files on the fly using the IView(i might be a bit wrong here since I have touched MVC in a few over a year) to create you memory view, render it( can be used to also replace you @ directives on the file) and then delete it.